# can useEffect wait setState(hook)?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code in useEffect (like componentDidMount):

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const idChat = props.match.params.id;
    const data = {
      idChat,
      user: props.user._id
    }
    authService.getChat(data)
    .then(res =>{
      const userChat = res.data.users.filter(e=> e!== data.user).toString()
      authService.getuser(userChat)
      .then(res=>{
        setOtherUser(res.data)
      })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      setErrors(err.response)
    })

  }, [])
```

This code run once.  Ok.

I need another useEffect that use a `otherUser` state. But it isn't seted yet.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  socket.readUsers(users => {
    const is = users.users.indexOf(otherUser._id);
    console.log(users,otherUser._id, is)
    if(is < 0){
      setUsersStatus(false)
    }else{
      setUsersStatus(true)
    }
  });
 })
```

if i do condicitional, never enter into if :/
How can i call otherUser in useEffect?

Comment: Add `otherUser` as dependency of your second `useEffect` and check when `otherUser` is not null to execute the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it as a dependency of the effect. You can then just skip executing the code when `otherUser` isn't set.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (otherUser) {
    socket.readUsers(users => {
      const is = users.users.indexOf(otherUser._id);
      console.log(users, otherUser._id, is);
      if (is < 0) {
        setUsersStatus(false);
      } else {
        setUsersStatus(true);
      }
    });
  }
}, [otherUser]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add otherUser user as this shape in  with dependent of the otherUser as second parameter as arry[otherUser]

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(otherUser){....}
},[otherUser])
```